# Declare in C == define in C++?

Tags: c++, c, initialization, declaration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

Is it correct that to declare in C is equal to define in C++?

```
int a;     /* to declare variabel a in C */
int b = 2; /* to declare and initialize in C */


int c;     // to define in C++ 
int d = 4; // to define and initialize in C++
```

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration

Comment: _Is it correct that to declare in C is equal to define in C++?_ No,that makes no sense.Declaration and Definition are two different terms. Every definition is a declaration but every declaration is not a definition. For more info click the link that I have given.

Answer (score 2):

No.

For functions, I've seen "declare" being used for just writing the header, whereas "define" was used for writing the body.

However, it's all natural language. "declare" as in you C example seems correct for both C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

In C, declaring means to tell the compiler it exists whereas defining is assigning an actual value to it.

I see no reason why this would be different in C++

Answer (score 0):

yes 
it should be